# How to strip everything after the pattern "On x John wrote:" in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large string (coming from reading an email). Now when an user replies, a typical reply looks as follows:

```
"On x x x wrote:"
```

I would like to strip out all the text that comes after this pattern. However, I am not sure how to identify this pattern.

I know how to strip out everything after a certain word or character:

```
abc = abc.split('From:', 1)[0]
```

But what do you do when you have text in between the patterns `On` and `wrote:`?

Sample:

```
\r\nOn Tue, Feb 12, 2019 at 1:11 PM +0100, "Name" <email@email.com<mailto:email@email.com>> wrote:\r\n
```

Comment: This is harder than you think. Different email clients use different phrases (not invariably in English) and different date formats.

Comment: Does the line always end with the `wrote:`

Comment: Could you post a sample output?

Comment: @BoarGules I agree, and I haven't found a proper solution yet. Thus why I am trying to do it the dirty way just to have something in place. Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a regex will sort this:

```
re.match(r"\r\nOn.+wrote:", email)[0]
```

`^` indicates start of string
`On` is the word "On"
`.+` is one or more instances of anything
`wrote:` is the word "wrote"

the `[0]` at the end will get the first match from the email
the `email.strip()` removes whitespace

example:

```
import re

email =  '\r\nOn Tue, Feb 12, 2019 at 1:11 PM +0100, "Name" <email@email.com<mailto:email@email.com>> wrote:\r\n'
extracted = re.match(r"On.+wrote:", email.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', ''))[0]
print(extracted)

Out[163]: 'On Tue, Feb 12, 2019 at 1:11 PM +0100, "Name" <email@email.com<mailto:email@email.com>> wrote:'
```

an alternative to a regex, is to find the index of the first occurrence of the word "On", and the index of the word "wrote", and subset the whole text between those:

```
extracted = email[email.find('On'):email[email.find('On'):].find('wrote:')+8]
```

Comment: Hmm I get: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Basically he does not find the expression.

Comment: can you give an example email response? perhaps there are leading characters in the string, in which case you might need to remove the `^`

Comment: \r\nOn Tue, Feb 12, 2019 at 1:11 PM +0100, "Name" <email@email.com<mailto:email@email.com>> wrote:\r\n

Comment: @JohnAndrews and the output of that should be?

Comment: The problem it seems is that there is basically \r\n in front and \r\n after. Updating above example.

Comment: Yeah I see why it would work in your case, but in my case the amount of space is not fixed. I have like \r\n\r\n\r\n I can't try out all combinations.

Comment: ah, you should use `str.strip()` on the email itself to sanitise, updated

Comment: Still not working in my example. This is impossible. Thanks for the tips so far

Comment: removed the caret, this should now find it anywhere within the full email text

Comment: .strip() does not remove the \r\n in my example. This did: re.sub(r"[\r\n]*", "", abc) but it still does not find the pattern (even when removing the ^)

Comment: `email.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')` is the last thing to try i suppose, without having the entire email example

Comment: Ill accept it as an answer but in my case it didnt work. I have no clue why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188343/discussion-between-zulfiqaar-and-johnandrews).

Answer (score 1):

abc.split("on.*wrote:")[1]

https://regexr.com
this is a great site to learn regex!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex, and then when you have the exact match can split it.
You can use /On/regex/From:/, where regex is a regular expression to detect "x x x".

More info can be found in the docs: [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to find your pattern:

```
 /(?:On\ x\ x\ x\ wrote\:)/
```

Comment: x x x is just an example, it could be anything

Comment: /(?:On)(?:.*)(?:Wrote)/  - This would search for anything between "On" and "Wrote".